# Bad weight detection for unit in math mode with siunitx?

Tags: luatex, siunitx

Here is a (minimal) code example showing the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[noload=abbr]{siunitx}
\sisetup{decimalsymbol=comma,detect-all}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Text : \SI{2}{cm}.
\item Math : $\SI{2}{cm}$.
\item Bold Text : \textbf{\SI{2}{cm}}.
\item Bold Math : $\symbf{\SI{2}{cm}}$.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result.

[image]

The last unit should be in bold style.

Comment: I'll post an 'answer' here later though it will mainly be  a discussion of the issues!

Comment: I don't have LuaTeX installed, but with pdflatex using `\bfseries${\SI{2}{cm}}$` seems to work.

Comment: @Andrew : seems not working with luatex, and I need a 'bold-stype' commande that I can use in math mode.

Answer (score 3):

At present I don't have a 'do X' fix for this, but I can explain why the issue arises and note that I am giving it some thought.

The 'traditional' math font set up in TeX uses a series of different font families to deliver different appearance. Inside `siunitx`, I use this to detect `\mathsf` and `\mathtt` (as opposed to roman text) by looking at the `\fam` value. Bold is handled differently as LaTeX offers `\boldmath` as a switch for all of the material in one math mode section, and indeed due to the way TeX works this *cannot* (safely) be applied inside math mode. This can be detected as  being on/off using the LaTeX internal data structures. What `siunitx` has never done is check for `\mathbf`(I will return to this below).

The Unicode math font approach is entirely different to the above: only one `\fam` is ever used and switching takes place by picking the correct mapping of input to output. In `unicode-math` this can be detected from another internal variable. However, that alone would not be enough as the way `siunitx` sets up the output is also aimed at the traditional set up. What the package does is effectively

```
\text{\unboldmath\ensuremath{<content>}}
```

as this avoids any 'accidental' bold text (remember `\boldmath` and the reverse only works around an entire math mode block). That fails to work properly with `unicode-math` as the font approach is entirely different.

Hindsight being a wonderful thing, I would take a different take to detecting fonts (or not) if I was starting from scratch. In particular, I'd ignore `\mathsf`, `\mathtt`, *etc.* entirely and just worry about the 'surrounding text' setting: really the math mode mark-up should not be interpreted as giving 'design' information. I'd also do the 'detection' in a different way, forcing only such font changes as are needed. However, the question is whether I can do that and not break too many documents.

I'm working sporadically on a third version of `siunitx` and this is one thing to look at for it. At present, I'm not sure if I can do what would be a very useful update from my point of view (clearer internals) whilst keeping everyone's documents unchanged (the basics are fine, it's the awkward outputs that are hard). What I will do is look at this area first in a v3 context and then in terms of what can be moved back into v2. The latter is more tricky as some of the internal set up really depends on the classical TeX math approach.